# How to resolve "Error in gsub" with removeWords in R

Tags: r, gsub, tm

I have a dataframe containing tweets. I'm working to delete the stop words and for this reason I used:

```
stopWords <- stopwords("en")
tweets_sample$text<-removeWords(tweets_sample$text,stopWords)
```

Anyway, I obtained

```
Error in gsub(sprintf("(*UCP)\\b(%s)\\b", paste(sort(words, decreasing = TRUE),  : 
input string 1 is invalid UTF-8
```

What would account for that kind of error?

Comment: tweets_sample <- as.data.frame(c(1,2,3))
tweets_sample$text <- c("this is an example", "this is an example too", "that's it")

tweets_sample$text
stopWords <- stopwords("en")
tweets_sample$text<-removeWords(tweets_sample$text,stopWords) ; it works for me...

Comment: I have encountered this issue when my input contained `\uFFFF` char.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like an encoding issue. Try `Encoding(tweets_sample$text) <- "UTF-8"`and then the `removeWords` function.

Answer (score 1):

looks like you have invalid UTF-8 in your first string.
you could use `iconv` to replace any non-convertible bytes in your text:

```
text <- "your text"
Encoding(te\xE7xt) <- "UTF-8"
iconv(text, "UTF-8", "UTF-8",sub='')
```

"text"